# Create Async Wrapper for a NonAsync Method

Tags: c#

I am writting a middleware for Asp.Net Identity UserStore where the caller expects a Task and the Method to be called is NonAsynch.

```
Task IUserSecurityStampStore<T, string>.SetSecurityStampAsync(T user, string stamp)
{


    var res = Utility.SetSecurityStamp(user, stamp); // needs to be called as Async

    var identityUser = ToIdentityUser(res);

    SetApplicationUser(user, identityUser);

    return ??? ; // How do i get a task to return here ?

}
```

How do i  return a Task out of res and stamp? Tried `Task.FromResult` but it says only one type argument is allowed.

Comment: Very confusing what you have trouble with... Possibly just `Task.FromResult` is the solution (if it is the case you may want to edit your question to make it clear that you need synchronous method to be compatible with async siganture/be `await`-able)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It says Task.FromResult requires one type argument. I just want to return a Task from the result res and stamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the [async/await pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).
- Wrap the call of the `Utility.SetSecurityStamp` method into a `Task` using [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx)

So your code could become something like that:

```
async Task IUserSecurityStampStore<T, string>.SetSecurityStampAsync(T user, string stamp)
{
    var res = await Task.Run(() => Utility.SetSecurityStamp(user, stamp));
    var identityUser = ToIdentityUser(res);
    SetApplicationUser(user, identityUser);
}
```

Or you can just use [Task.FromResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx) to make your method awaitable :

```
async Task IUserSecurityStampStore<T, string>.SetSecurityStampAsync(T user, string stamp)
{
    var res = Utility.SetSecurityStamp(user, stamp);
    var identityUser = ToIdentityUser(res);
    SetApplicationUser(user, identityUser);

    await Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the utility method is nonAsync over which i have no control.So can't use await

Comment: what is the return type of your Utility.SetSecurityStamp method ? Is it a longt time running process ?

Comment: It returns type T and does some DB operations so yes it can be a long time running process.

Comment: You can use Task.Run to wrap your non awaitable call. I've edited my post

Comment: In 1st example await has to be removed. In the second example what does 0 mean?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the await in the first sample ? if you remove it the execution of the Utility.SetSecurityStamp will continue after the call the SetSecurityStampAsync. In the second example, I use a Task.FromResult to make the method awaitable but here we don't care about the result so I use 0... It's just a trick.

Comment: i get compile error because of await. saying it can only be used with an async method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108349/discussion-between-thomas-and-deb).

Comment: In essence you can make it awaitable by returning `Task.FromResult("What you intend to return");` like in the 2nd code snippet. If you intend to return the result from `SetApplicationUser(user, identityUser);` then `Task.FromResult(SetApplicationUser(user, identityUser))`